# python: регулярное выражение для выделения числа из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

подскажите как с помощью регулярки выполнить следующую задачу:

есть ссылка:

```
http://адрес/путь/путь/путь/страница.html
```

причем `путь` может содержать числа - например `xxx-123-456-yyy`

```
страница обязательно содержит числа в формате текст<число>текст<число>текст....<число>текст.html
```

необходимо выделить из полной ссылки число, которое первым находится на странице.html

т.е. если есть ссылка

```
http://link.ru/123-456/text789/1122-hi-90.html
```

то было бы выделено именно 1122

P.S.

я могу это сделать в лоб через split(), но это очень криво, поэтому хочется красивую регулярку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
link = "http://link.ru/123-456/text789/1122-hi-90.html"
print(re.search(r"\d+(?!.*/)", link)[0])
```

Ищет первое число после которого далее по строке точно нет слеша.

Answer (score 1):

А ещё можно воспользоваться `urllib.parse` и парочкой `split`:

```py
from urllib import parse
url = r'htt'+'p://link.ru/123-456/text789/1122-hi-90.html'
print(parse.urlsplit(url).path.rsplit('/')[-1].split('-')[0])
# => 1122
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/rUvb6E).

- `parse.urlsplit(url).path` -> `/123-456/text789/1122-hi-90.html`
- `....rsplit('/')[-1]` -> `1122-hi-90.html`
- `....split('-')[0]` -> `1122`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
link = "http://link.ru/123-456/text789/1122-hi-90.html"
print(re.sub(r'^.+/(\d+).*$', r'\1', link))
#1122
```